# Switching scenes in JavaFX using a button

Tags: java, oop, javafx

Hey guys I'm writing a program that requires me to be able to switch scenes where one of them I can get information from the user. I've watched a few YouTube videos now followed all the instructions and have troubleshooted a lot. I can swear I have the right code and I know all my files are in the right place and all connect to the controller with all their corresponding variables and methods. Yet every time I run my code It works until I press the button to switch scenes (addTask method). I do have no idea why it doesn't switch, nothing happens and just gives me an error when I press the button.

As I said I have tried all different types of solutions I could find online but still nothing works. Every time I click the button to switch scenes it just errors and does not switch.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

    ZonedDateTime dateFocus;
    ZonedDateTime today;
    private Stage stage2;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    @FXML
    private Text currentMonth;

    @FXML
    private Text currentYear;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pane;

    private Stage mainWindow; // Define mainWindow as a variable of type Stage

    public void setMainWindow(Stage mainWindow) {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }
    @FXML
    private TextField desc;

    @FXML
    private TextField duedate;

    @FXML
    private TextField priority;

    @FXML
    private TextField title;

    @FXML
    private Text someText;

    @FXML
    private Button doneButton;
    

    @FXML
    void backMonth(ActionEvent event) {

        int i = 0;
        while (i < pane.getChildren().size()) {
            Node n = pane.getChildren().get(i);
            if (n instanceof StackPane) {
                pane.getChildren().remove(n);
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        dateFocus = dateFocus.minusMonths(1);
        drawpane();
        
    }

    @FXML
    void forwardMonth(ActionEvent event) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < pane.getChildren().size()) { 
            Node n = pane.getChildren().get(i);
            if (n instanceof StackPane) {
                pane.getChildren().remove(n);
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }       
        dateFocus = dateFocus.plusMonths(1);
      
        drawpane();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        dateFocus = ZonedDateTime.now();
        today = ZonedDateTime.now();
        drawpane();
    }

    @FXML
    void addTask(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("taskScene.fxml"));
        stage2 = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage2.setScene(scene);
        stage2.show();
        
    }
    @FXML
    void addHWTask(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    }
    @FXML
    void addWorkTask(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    }
    @FXML
    void doneTask(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    }
    

    public void drawpane(){
        currentYear.setText(String.valueOf(dateFocus.getYear()));
        currentMonth.setText(String.valueOf(dateFocus.getMonth()));

        double paneWidth = pane.getPrefWidth();
        double paneHeight = pane.getPrefHeight();
        double strokeWidth = 1;
        
        double spacingH = 9;
        double spacingV = 9;
        int y = 140; //Buffer
        int x = 9; //Buffer
   

        int monthMaxDate = dateFocus.getMonth().maxLength();
        //Check for leap year
        if(dateFocus.getYear() % 4 != 0 && monthMaxDate == 29){
            monthMaxDate = 28;
        }
        int dateOffset = ZonedDateTime.of(dateFocus.getYear(), dateFocus.getMonthValue(), 1,0,0,0,0,dateFocus.getZone()).getDayOfWeek().getValue();
        if(dateOffset == 7){
            dateOffset = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                
                StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                rectangle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                rectangle.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
                double rectangleWidth =(paneWidth/7) - strokeWidth - spacingH;
                rectangle.setWidth(rectangleWidth);
                double rectangleHeight = .8 * (paneHeight/6) - strokeWidth - spacingV;
                rectangle.setHeight(rectangleHeight);
                stackPane.getChildren().add(rectangle);

                int calculatedDate = (j+1)+(7*i);
                if(calculatedDate > dateOffset || dateOffset == 0){
                    int currentDate = calculatedDate - dateOffset;
                    if(currentDate <= monthMaxDate){
                        Text date = new Text(String.valueOf(currentDate));
                        double textTranslationY = - (rectangleHeight / 2) * 0.75;
                        date.setTranslateY(textTranslationY);
                        stackPane.getChildren().add(date);
                    }
                    if(today.getYear() == dateFocus.getYear() && today.getMonth() == dateFocus.getMonth() && today.getDayOfMonth() == currentDate){
                        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
                  // Adjust the translation based on row and column indices
                  
                double stackPaneTranslateX = j * (rectangleWidth + spacingH)+x;
                double stackPaneTranslateY = i * (rectangleHeight + spacingV) +y;
                stackPane.setTranslateX(stackPaneTranslateX);
                stackPane.setTranslateY(stackPaneTranslateY);
                pane.getChildren().add(stackPane);
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Show your error message, code, and project structure.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/2423906

Comment: You need to provide the broken code ([mcve] - please read it) to get help with it.

Comment: Please put a system out into your method, click the button and tell us, if it was printed or not. To that, please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: Instead of "Scene = new Scene" try "stage.getScene().setRoot(root);" and remove that ".setScene()". Sometimes there is a strange behaviour in JFX, so that it does not realize that changes in the UI thread and it does not repaint it. In this case you can force the repainting with setting "width +=1 and width-=1".

Comment: Take a look at this class: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-SimpleJavaFxApplicationBase/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fwedasoft%2FsimpleJavaFxApplicationBase%2FsceneUtil%2FSceneUtil.java#L71

Comment: That is not really a minimal reproducible example.  Try to copy only the code in the question with no change or addition and run it to replicate only the issue you are trying to reproduce (you can't).  The answer I added generically addresses the question rather than your specific issue (which I don't know what the cause of is).

Comment: *”nothing happens and just gives me an error”*. Well, which? Does nothing happen, or does it give you an error (which is clearly something happening)? If it gives an error, did you read the error message? What did it tell you the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

To change the scene using a button:

In the button action, set the scene for the stage to another scene instance:

```
Button gotoScene2 = new Button("To Scene 2");
gotoScene2.setOnAction(e -> stage.setScene(scene2));
```

If you don't have a reference to the stage, you can get it from the button:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> ((Stage) button.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(newScene));
```

Normally, you don't need to set the scene, it is enough to set the root on the existing scene:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> button.getScene().setRoot(newRoot));
```

If you use FXML, it is no different, you load the FXML when the button is pressed, the loader returns a parent node and you set that as the new root of the scene.

Example application, which switches scenes using buttons.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SceneChangeApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button gotoScene1 = new Button("To Scene 1");
        Button gotoScene2 = new Button("To Scene 2");

        Scene scene1 = createScene(gotoScene2, Color.PALEGREEN);
        Scene scene2 = createScene(gotoScene1, Color.PAPAYAWHIP);

        gotoScene1.setOnAction(e -> stage.setScene(scene1));
        gotoScene2.setOnAction(e -> stage.setScene(scene2));

        stage.setScene(scene1);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Scene createScene(Button button, Color color) {
        Pane layout = new StackPane(button);
        layout.setBackground(Background.fill(color));

        return new Scene(
                layout,
                160, 80, color
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```